# Android: How to fetch cursor all rows given a specific column values

Tags: android, sqlite

First of all, please consider I have minimal experience with SQLite.
I am writing an app in Java for the Android platform and I've run into an issue while attempting to query a SQLite database.

I have implemented a database and I am unsure of how to write a method which returns a cursor of only specific rows with a certain value in a certain column.
Say there is a column titled "persons_name", I would like to write a method which returns all the rows that have the same  column values.

I know how to write a fetchAll() method and how to write a fetch() for specific rows given an ID, but I not multiple specific rows.

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `query` command on the database, example taken from some of my code...

```
public Cursor getSubList(int parentKey) {

    String[] fields = new String[] {
            ARTICLE_ID,
            RM_HEADING,
            PAGE_PIC_THUMB,
            PAGE_READ,
            PAGE_DOWNLOADED,
            ARTICLE_ID + " as _id "
    };

    Cursor cursor = toolsDB.query(ARTICLE_TABLE,
            fields,
            PROGRAMME_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] {
                "" + parentKey
            },
            null,
            null,
            RM_HEADING);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

fields is the column names I want retrieved, the next parameter is the filtering field, then the value I want to filter on. I'm also ordering it on the column RM_HEADING

Here's more [details from the Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Its just another column I've defined from the table, its so I can order the results in the cursor